# Applying integral on normal distribution in Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I know what normal (Gaussian) distribution is and how we can find probability of certain range of any continuous random variable by applying integral on its probability density function (PDF), but how can it be done in python using Scipy, more specifically, using `scipy.stat.norm.pdf` and `scipy.integral.quad`.?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: you don't really need numerical quadrature. There's the `cdf` method in `scipy.stats` continuous random variable classes which uses fast implementation with special functions whenever possible.

Comment: @CongMa, thanks for that hint, after bit of research It cleared a lot of stuff. Initially, I was finding probability by coding [pdf equation](http://reliabilityanalyticstoolkit.appspot.com/static/normal_distribution_pdf_equation.gif) without using `sciPy` or `numPy` and then taking integral from range [-inf to some random variable], later, implemented `scipy.stat.norm.pdf`  and `scipy.integral.quad`. `cdf` equation made it quite easier. Now, I am stuck in multivariate cdf.